# How do you find the area?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I tried to use trigonometry to find the area but I found no formula.How can I can find the area of this triangle?[image]

Comment: By surface, do you mean area of the triangle?

Comment: If so, one method: use Law of Sines to figure out the other two sides, then use Heron's formula to find the area.

Comment: What is 'surface' here?.....Does it imply area?

Comment: Heron's formula:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to using Heron’s Formula:

The third angle is $180-(33+55)=92^\circ$. Using the Law of Sines, $$\frac{\sin 92^\circ }{4.7}=\frac{\sin 55^\circ}{a}\implies a \approx 3.852$$ where $a$ is the side opposite the $55^\circ$ angle. The area then is $$\frac 12 \sin 33^\circ (4.7)(3.852) \approx 4.93$$

Answer (score 1):

Use sine law:

$$\frac{a}{sinA}=\frac{b}{sinB}=\frac{c}{sinC}$$

to find the other sides.

$$\frac{4.7 km}{sin(180 -33-55 )^o}=\frac{b}{sin33^o}=\frac{c}{sin55^o}$$

From here either use [Heron's Formula.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) or

Consider a vector $\overrightarrow{x}$ from the point at $33^o$ angle to point opposite 4.7 km side , and another $\overrightarrow{y}$ from $33^o$ point to $55^o$ point.

Now the area is simply :

$$\Delta= \frac{1}{2} |\overrightarrow{x} \times \overrightarrow y| =\frac{1}{2}c(4.7 \ km)sin(33^o)$$

Comment: You may want to precede trigonometric functions' names with a backslash. The LaTeX/MathJax will know those are symbols and render them in an upright font with spacing appropriate for functions, instead of an amorphous blob of italic, variable-like letters. Please compare `2 sin a` → $2 sin a$ vs. `2 \sin a` → $2 \sin a$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $h$ be the height with respect to the base length $4.7$ and note that

$$4.7 = h\cot33+h\cot55$$

Then, the area is

$$Area= 
\frac12h(4.7)= \frac{4.7^2}{2(\cot33+\cot55)}$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

From figure you can see,
$$AD/CD=\cot \angle A$$ & $$BD/CD=\cot \angle B$$
So
$$AB/CD=(AD+BD)/CD=\cot \angle A+\cot \angle B$$

Applying this you get,
$$4.7/CD=\cot 55^° + \cot 33^° \implies CD=4.7/(\cot 55^° + \cot 33^°)$$

Hence area of the given triangle be:
$$\frac 12 . AB.CD=\frac 12 .(4.7).\frac{4.7}{(\cot 55^° + \cot 33^°)}$$